# error: array subscript is above array bounds for std::vector::insert

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2015

I am compiling with `-Werror` and found a warning translated to the error:

```
1>  cc1plus.exe: warnings being treated as errors
1>  c:\rtems-4.9\bin\../lib/gcc/powerpc-rtems4.9/4.3.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h: In function 'int someFunc()':
1>  D:\Git\Error_Parsing_script\Src\Plus\RTEMS_proj\c:\rtems-4.9\bin\..\lib\gcc\powerpc-rtems4.9\4.3.2\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h(1043,1) : error: array subscript is above array bounds
```

From this code:

```
struct ControllerConfigDataType1 {
    char name[50];
    int controllerType;
};

int someFunc()
{
    std::vector<char> reply;
    reply.reserve(255);
    ControllerConfigDataType1 response = { { 0 } };
    reply.insert(reply.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&response), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&response) + sizeof(response));
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, [this code is completely valid](http://ideone.com/ndIXaW). One peculiar thing is that if I manually set the `sizeof(resonse)` to <= 50 (the size of the char array) then we get no error. It seems that this error comes from trying to go outside the bounds of the `char name[50]` array in `response`, which i guess makes sense from my pointer de-reference `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&response) + sizeof(response)`.

**Knowing that the format of `ControllerConfigDataType1` cannot change, is there a way to satisfy the compilers reservations about this line?**

*Note that this is on a somewhat old compiler from RTEMS 4.9.2 (see details below), this may mean that this warning does not appear for more recent versions of GCC (and does not appear for Visual C++ from VS2015).*

### Other info

The error mentions `stl_vector.h(1043,1)` which is the implementation of the `std::vector::insert` function:

```
  // Called by the range insert to implement [23.1.1]/9
  template<typename _InputIterator>
    void
    _M_insert_dispatch(iterator __pos, _InputIterator __first,
           _InputIterator __last, __false_type)
    {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::
    iterator_category _IterCategory;
  _M_range_insert(__pos, __first, __last, _IterCategory());
}
```

**Indentation left as retrieved from library**

Note that the compiler is supplied from `RTEMS 4.9.2` and has the following version information:

```
Thread model: rtems
gcc version 4.3.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: Whenever I see `reinterpret_cast` in a code review, I start hunting for bugs (extra carefully) (beyond the cast itself that is) - there are usually a few.. just saying.

Comment: "gcc version 4.3.2" - that's pretty *old*. Completly unrelated to your question, but have you considered using a more modern compiler (and C++ language version)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl 1. Yes, but this is neccasary here and we have been very careful. 2. We cant, its tied to the OS, and an OS update will be a 6month - 1year project, dont have the resources.

Comment: Downvoter, a comment explaining what i can improve will help a lot, is this really a bad question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to obtain the bytes of an object is to use `memcpy`, and to let the byte type be `unsigned char`. It's good because the Holy Standard has at least one example of that, so that if a compiler chokes on it then it's easy to say, hey, this compiler chokes on an example from the standard, let's stop using it. Even if examples in ISO standards are non-normative.

---

Your original example, with this approach:

```
int someFunc1()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> reply;
    reply.reserve(255);     // Note: this, from original example, is only an optimization.
    ControllerConfigDataType1 response = { { 0 } };
//  reply.insert(reply.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&response), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&response) + sizeof(response));
    int rs = reply.size(); int ds = sizeof(response); reply.resize(rs+ds); memcpy(&reply[rs], &response, ds);
    return 0;
}
```

This code assumes that `int` is sufficient for the size of a `vector` as used here, which is reasonable for a network packet: it can't very well be 2 GB or more. Otherwise replace the `int` with a `ptrdiff_t`. Possibly renamed as `Size`.

---

More generally you can abstract that up and centralize it, which can help with both testing and maintenance, like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t
#include <string.h>     // memcpy
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_trivially_copyable
#include <utility>      // std::enable_if_t

using Byte = unsigned char;
using Size = ptrdiff_t;

template< class Type
    // The following sanity-check line must be removed for a C++03 compiler:
    , class Enabled_ = std::enable_if_t< std::is_trivially_copyable< Type >::value >
    >
void append_to( std::vector<Byte>& v, Type const& o )
{
    Size const n_v_bytes = v.size();
    Size const n_o_bytes = sizeof( o );
    v.resize( n_v_bytes + n_o_bytes );
    memcpy( &v[n_v_bytes], &o, n_o_bytes );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, that's why the downvote. The question is "why do I have compiler warning", your silly answer is "use memcpy".

Comment: We moved from a `memcpy` to a `std::vector` to make easily expandable memory, we didn't really want to move back, not my downvote though.

Comment: @Paul: It's your **opinion** that it doesn't answer the question. Can you please elaborate on that, how, you think, it doesn't answer the question? I'm interested in your thinking (the phenomenon in general).

Comment: @Ben: you can use `memcpy` with `std::vector`, that's not a problem.

Comment: I added to my comment about why it doesn't answer the question. Also, it is for sure my opinion and I express my opinion via downvoting unhelpful answers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But it wont allocate space for you automatically, hence, insert ...

Comment: @Ben: It's trivial to allocate space. It's also shorter code than you have.

Comment: @Paul: Thank you. You have not read the question. Your **alleged quote** is not a quote. Here is the question, verbatim: "Knowing that the format of ControllerConfigDataType1 cannot change, is there a way to satisfy the compilers reservations about this line?".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sure, but is the `insert` code invalid? I know that using `memcpy` will be a good workaround, but I thought that this was fine also ...

Comment: @Ben: I think you'll find it can be argued both ways. Some people have a very strict interpretation of the standard, and think g++ "strict aliasing" checking expresses the rules exactly. Others (including me) think not. But what matters in practice is how to write portable code, including catering to that compiler. `memcpy` is one solution in your case.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Is the question actually a bad one, i thought i conformed to the question guidelines well, it is a bit specific, but I dont think the question is bad ...

Comment: @Ben: As I see it the question is good. It's answerable. My answer may not be perfect, and it's certainly not complete in all possible details, but it illustrates that it's a reasonable question with a reasonable single answer (or single main direction of answer).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah, just been bombarded with downvotes lately for what i thought were well asked questions. I am changing to a memcpy now we will see how it goes. +1, thanks for your help.

Comment: I would like to follow this up, can you give a short example of how to `memcpy` into a vector? You say its shorter then using insert, but the only way i can figure to do it is: `   reply.resize(reply.size() + sizeof data1); memcpy(&reply[reply.size() - sizeof data1], reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data1), sizeof data1);`

Comment: @Ben: Done. Happily it turned out that the code really was shorter. I only guessed that. :)